Webscraping a page with a dynamic table using R
I am trying to webscrape the table from the following page using R (rvest)
https://www.nba.com/stats/players/passing?DateFrom=02/07/2024&DateTo=02/07/2024&dir=1
However I noticed that the table itself has 3 pages but when I click to the 2nd and 3rd page the URL does not change at all.
Does anyone know how to webscrape the 147 rows from the table using R please?
I have tried the following with no luck
page <- read_html("https://www.nba.com/stats/players/passing?DateFrom=02/07/2024&DateTo=02/07/2024&dir=1")
  
contentnodes <-page %>% html_nodes ("div.l-content.pre-quench") %>% 
    html_attr("q-data") %>% jsonlite::fromJSON()

Thanks in advance

To complete with an rvest solution (it's wiser to use the API option as suggested by @Kat) :
### Setup chromote which is used by rvest (path to MS Edge is used here)
Sys.setenv(
  CHROMOTE_CHROME = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe"
)

### Load the package 
library(rvest)

### Interact with the webpage (selecting the button to load all the results, then display them)
a=read_html_live("https://www.nba.com/stats/players/passing?DateFrom=02/07/2024&DateTo=05/21/2024&page=all")
a$click(css = 'div[class*="Pagination_pageDropdown"] select',n_clicks = 1)
a$press(css='div[class*="Pagination_pageDropdown"] select',key_code = 'ArrowUp')
a$scroll_into_view(css = 'div[class*="FooterLegalSection_legalCopy"]')
a %>% html_elements(css='table[class*="Crom_table"]') %>% html_table()

Output :
# A tibble: 213 × 16
   PLAYER            TEAM     GP     W     L   MIN PassesMade
   <chr>             <chr> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 A.J. Lawson       DAL       7     5     2   2.3        1.6
 2 AJ Green          MIL       6     2     4  11.2        9.3
 3 Aaron Gordon      DEN      12     7     5  37.1       38  
 4 Aaron Nesmith     IND      13     8     5  32.7       35.6
 5 Aaron Wiggins     OKC      10     6     4  15.7       12.2
 6 Al Horford        BOS      10     8     2  28.6       28.1
 7 Alec Burks        NYK       6     2     4  20.1       17.5
 8 Amir Coffey       LAC       6     2     4  18.7       13  
 9 Andre Jackson Jr. MIL       5     1     4  11.9       16.6
10 Andrew Nembhard   IND      13     8     5  32         39  
# ℹ 203 more rows
# ℹ 9 more variables: PassesReceived <dbl>, AST <dbl>,
#   SecondaryAST <dbl>, PotentialAST <dbl>,
#   `AST PTSCreated` <dbl>, `AST PTSCreated` <dbl>,
#   ASTAdj <dbl>, `AST ToPass%` <dbl>,
#   `AST ToPass% Adj` <lgl>

EDIT : To get data for each day, in a less reliable way than the API, we can use something like this :
### Load the package 
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

### Setup chromote which is used by rvest (path to MS Edge is used here)
Sys.setenv(
  CHROMOTE_CHROME = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe"
)

### Load the packages
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

### Declare columns names.
### They'll be used to fix the table returned by rvest later
colnames = c(
  "PLAYER",
  "TEAM",
  "GP",
  "W",
  "L",
  "MIN",
  "PassesMade",
  "PassesReceived",
  "AST",
  "SecondaryAST",
  "PotentialAST",
  "AST_PTSCreated",
  "ASTAdj",
  "AST_ToPass%",
  "AST_ToPass%_Adj",
  "dummy"
)

### Get the dates of every match of the regular season
### We use basketball-reference.com here
calendrier=read_html("https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2024_games.html")

### The regular season starts in october and ends in april
### We get the url of each month
urls=calendrier %>% html_elements(xpath = '//div[@class="filter"]//a') %>% html_attr("href")
season=paste0("https://www.basketball-reference.com",urls[1:7])

### Function to get the date from each url
ext_dates = function(x) {
  a = read_html(x)
  b = a %>%
    html_element(xpath = "//table") %>%
    html_table %>% select(Date,Notes)
}

### We apply the function for each page (month)
cal=map(season,ext_dates,.progress = TRUE)

### We bind the result and extract the dates before the 16th april (end of the regular season)
dates=bind_rows(cal) %>%
  filter(Notes==""|is.na(Notes)) %>%
  select(-Notes) %>% 
  mutate(fix_date=mdy(Date)) %>% 
  filter(fix_date<ymd("2024-04-16")) %>% 
  mutate(fix_date=as.character(fix_date)) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  pull(fix_date)

### We write a function to read and extract data for each date
### Note we're using "Sys.sleep" in order to wait for the page to load completely
### The code can manage when the data is splitted on multiple pages or not

nba = function(x) {
  url=paste0("https://www.nba.com/stats/players/passing?DateFrom=",x,"&DateTo=",x,"&page=all&SeasonType=Regular%20Season")
  a = read_html_live(url)
  Sys.sleep(3)
  c = a %>% html_element('div[class*="Pagination_pageDropdown"] select') %>% length()
  if (c != 0) {
    a$press(css = 'div[class*="Pagination_pageDropdown"] select', key_code = 'ArrowUp')
    a$scroll_into_view(css = 'div[class*="FooterLegalSection_legalCopy"]')
  }
  Sys.sleep(3)
  temp = a %>% html_element(css = 'table[class*="Crom_table"]') %>% html_table() %>%
    setNames(colnames) %>%
    select(-dummy) %>%
    mutate(date = x, .before = 1)
  a$session$close()
  rm(a)
  gc()
  return(temp)
}

### We apply the function to each date and bind the results
out=map(dates,possibly(nba,tibble(date=NA_character_)),.progress = TRUE)
fin=bind_rows(out)

### We can check if all dates have been correctly scraped with
setdiff(dates,fin$date)

### If there's some missing data, we rerun the code for these specific dates
check_dates=setdiff(dates,fin$date)
out_2=map(check_dates,possibly(nba,tibble(date=NA_character_)),.progress = TRUE)
fix=bind_rows(out_2)

### We combine the second table with the first one to have a complete dataset
fix$date[is.na(fix$date)]<-setdiff(check_dates,fix$date)
test=fin %>% filter(!is.na(PLAYER)) %>% bind_rows(fix) %>% arrange(date)

### We check if there's still missing data with
test %>% filter(is.na(PLAYER))

Output (~24.5K rows):
# A tibble: 24,617 × 16
   date       PLAYER    TEAM     GP     W     L   MIN PassesMade PassesReceived   AST SecondaryAST PotentialAST AST_PTSCreated ASTAdj `AST_ToPass%`
   <chr>      <chr>     <chr> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>      <dbl>          <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>  <dbl>         <dbl>
 1 2023-10-24 Aaron Go… DEN       1     1     0  35           32             27     5            0           10             12      5          15.6
 2 2023-10-24 Andrew W… GSW       1     0     1  27.3         15             20     0            1            1              0      1           0  
 3 2023-10-24 Anthony … LAL       1     0     1  34.2         41             39     4            1            6             10      5           9.8
 4 2023-10-24 Austin R… LAL       1     0     1  31.3         39             37     4            0            8              9      4          10.3
 5 2023-10-24 Braxton … DEN       1     1     0   0.7          0              0     0            0            0              0      0           0  
 6 2023-10-24 Cam Redd… LAL       1     0     1  17.6          8              5     0            0            1              0      0           0  
 7 2023-10-24 Chris Pa… GSW       1     0     1  34.2         66             69     9            1           24             24     11          13.6
 8 2023-10-24 Christia… DEN       1     1     0  19.3         25             23     2            0            3              5      2           8  
 9 2023-10-24 Christia… LAL       1     0     1  15.5         10              8     0            0            0              0      0           0  
10 2023-10-24 Collin G… DEN       1     1     0   0.7          0              0     0            0            0              0      0           0  
# ℹ 24,607 more rows
# ℹ 1 more variable: `AST_ToPass%_Adj` <dbl>
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

Note : stats for the 9th March 2024 are missing from the NBA website.

Thanks for providing this. I get the following error when running the a$click part
Error in new_chromote && !self$session$is_active() :
invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
Any idea what the issue is?

Yes. You have to setup chromote before using rvest function. Post has been edited.

Thank you. I get this error now

a$click(css = 'div[class*="Pagination_pageDropdown"] select',n_clicks = 1)
Error in private$wait_for_selector():
! Failed to find selector "div[class*="Pagination_pageDropdown"] select" in 5 seconds.
rlang::last_trace()
<error/rlang_error>


Yes. URL was wrong (2x 02/07/2024 in it). Post has been updated with the following timespan : 02/07/2024 to 05/21/2024. It should work fine.

Sorry one follow up question, I am trying to extract 1 day at at time, i.e. to and from are the same date. Any idea why it works for some days for but for others? As an example it does not work for Oct24 or Oct26 but it works for Oct25 and Oct27?

Yes. That's because for Oct24 and Oct26, data isn't split on multiple pages. Code needs to be adapted a little bit. I can do it later if needed.

ohhh that makes sense. Would you be able to show me how to adapt the code please? What I am intending to do is to basically run a loop to scrape the data where each iteration is a new day

Post has been updated with a solution. Depending on you configuration, it should take approximately 20 minutes to get all the data for the regular season.

Thank you so much for taking the time to code this up, it is really appreciated!

sorry to bother you mate but I have tried rerunning this code several months later and it doesnt seem to work anymore. Do you know why that might be?

I started going into how to make this happen with rvest, but on a hunch, because I'm sure there's an API for NBA.com, I looked for an R package that uses that API. I found one, but every function gives me an error. However, it does 99% of the work for you, so even if it's erroring out...it's very useful.
Here's the BLUF (bottom-line, up-front)...or what's the more trendy way of saying that? drawing a blank...

I'll start with the very short answer after that I'll explain the answer in detail.

BLUF
Using the package and library from NBAr, call the function get_tracking. I used the dates in the URL you were using in your question as parameters.
devtools::install_github("PatrickChodowski/NBAr")
library(NBAr)

# capture out - captures URL and error message
gimme <- capture.output(get_tracking(season = 2023, type = "Player", measure_type = "Passing", 
                                     date_from = "02/07/2024", date_to = "02/07/2024"))

Next, I've provided a function that is taken from the code behind get_tracking (more detail in the "full explanation").
res <- rawToChar(GET(gimme[1], 
                     add_headers(.headers = c(
  'Referer' = 'http://google.com', 
  "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36",
  'connection' = 'keep-alive',
  'Accept' = 'application/json',
  'Host' = 'stats.nba.com',
  'x-nba-stats-origin'= 'stats')))$content) %>% fromJSON()
df1 <- res$resultSets$rowSet %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  setNames(tolower(unlist(res$resultSets$headers[1])))

df1 has all 147 rows from the URL you wanted to scrape.
The full explanation
Install the library and/or call the library.
devtools::install_github("PatrickChodowski/NBAr")
library(NBAr)

I used the function get_tracking.
When I called it, I used the parameters in the url in your question:
gimme <- capture.output(get_tracking(season = 2023, type = "Player", measure_type = "Passing", 
                                     date_from = "02/07/2024", date_to = "02/07/2024"))

What the function returns is a very long URL and [1] "Can't convert replace  to match type of data ."

The error is from a function internal to the package called check_if_numeric. Not something too difficult to fix on the package side, but unnecessary to answer your question.

The objects result_sets_df, index, and dataset from within get_tracking are consolidated into what I named res and df1.
Calling get_tracking - no parameters, no parentheses or going to the Github code will give you a behind the scenes look at this function.
res <- rawToChar(GET(gimme[1],    # code taken from `get_tracking`
                     add_headers(.headers = c(
  'Referer' = 'http://google.com', 
  "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36",
  'connection' = 'keep-alive',
  'Accept' = 'application/json',
  'Host' = 'stats.nba.com',
  'x-nba-stats-origin'= 'stats')))$content) %>% fromJSON()
df1 <- res$resultSets$rowSet %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  setNames(tolower(unlist(res$resultSets$headers[1])))

This returned a dataset of 147 rows, 18 variables, matching the data you wanted from your URL in your question.

Thank you for sharing this code. When I run it though, df1 gets returned as a dataset of 0 observations of 0 variables. Any idea what the issue would be?

What do you see in your object gimme after you catch the output of get_tracking? Any warnings in the console from any of the functions?


gimme
[1] "http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashptstats?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom=02/07/2024&DateTo=02/07/2024&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&Height=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&PtMeasureType=Passing&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerOrTeam=Player&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2023-24&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight="


had to split over two comments due to character limit, this is the rest. Note that gimme was a value rather than object
[2] "[1] "Can't convert replace  to match type of data .""

Okay, that warning/error was expected, which is why I had said you call to collect the output from the function get_tracking. Do you see a web address in the object you created from capture.output? It should be a list where the 2nd element is the web address.
